# How to define mapping in elasticsearch for a special case?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to store document of type "cities" in elasticsearch for various cities and what was the rainfall metrics in those cities. Followings are two sample documents:

```
{
  "name": "Seattle"
  "rain_fall": {
    "jan16": {"max": 1000, "min": 1000, "avg": 1200 }, 
    "feb16": {"max": 1100, "min": 1000, "avg": 1200 },
    "mar16": {"max": 1800, "min": 1000, "avg": 1200 } 
  }
}

{
  "name": "London"
  "rain_fall": {
    "jan16": {"max": 1200, "min": 1000, "avg": 1200 }, 
    "feb16": {"max": 1300, "min": 1000, "avg": 1200 },
    "mar16": {"max": 1400, "min": 1000, "avg": 1200 } 
  }
}
```

How to define corrosponding mapping for above sampel documents? I managed to have this so far -

```
"mappings": {
  "_index": "myindex",
  "cities": {
    "dynamic": "strict", 
    "properties": {
      "name" {"type": "string"},
      "rain_fall": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          ----???----
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it like that, you're going to have new object properties being created for each month `jan16`, `feb16`, etc. Each month, you're going to create a new property and I'm not sure it's the most efficient way. It depends on how you want to query that index afterwards, but instead, I'd suggest to move the month as a new property inside the nested objects, like this:

```
{
  "name": "London",
  "rain_fall": [
    {"month": "jan16", "max": 1200, "min": 1000, "avg": 1200 }, 
    {"month": "feb16", "max": 1300, "min": 1000, "avg": 1200 },
    {"month": "mar16", "max": 1400, "min": 1000, "avg": 1200 } 
  ]
}
```

The mapping would then look like:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "cities": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "rain_fall": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "avg": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "min": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "month": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "max": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val. That's what I have also thought of.